# Dark and Light mode in xamarin android programatically

Tags: xamarin.android

Anyone have an idea how to change the theme Dark and Light mode in xamarin android programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

First, the Dark theme is available in Android 10 (API level 29) and higher. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/darktheme#force_dark

If you want to change the theme programatically, Apps must opt-in to Force Dark by setting `android:forceDarkAllowed="true"` in the activity's theme.

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
<!-- Customize your theme here. -->
<item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
<item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
<item name="android:forceDarkAllowed">true</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

And then, to switch the theme, call the code below to force dark in **OnCreate()**.

```
((AppCompatActivity)this).Delegate.SetLocalNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.ModeNightYes);
```

Call the code below to disable.

```
  ((AppCompatActivity)this).Delegate.SetLocalNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.ModeNightNo);
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I have now searched over 3 days for a solution for the night only mode.